# How to send a message to an azure service bus queue from an app service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an app service (rest api) which, as a proof of concept, I'm trying to send a message to a service bus queue.

I added the Microsoft identity provider, and disabled authentication because I want the service to have no authentication requirements but I needed a service principal for the app service.

Then, in the service bus queue, I added a role assignment for the Azure Service Bus Data Sender role and added the Service Principal that I created by adding the identity provider to the app service (app reg and enterprise app objects created from that step).

Then in my app I have this code:

```
var ns = configuration["namespace"]; 
var queueName = configuration["queue"];

// name of your Service Bus queue
// the client that owns the connection and can be used to create senders and receivers
await using (ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(ns, new DefaultAzureCredential(), clientOptions))
// the sender used to publish messages to the queue
await using (ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(queueName))
{
    ServiceBusMessage msg = new ServiceBusMessage("Test")
    {
        ContentType = singleStream.Headers.ContentType.ToString(),
        CorrelationId = correlationID,
        Subject = "Submission",
        
    };

    msg.ApplicationProperties.Add("Context.ContentType", contextData.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
    msg.ApplicationProperties.Add("Message.ContentType", messageData.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
    msg.ApplicationProperties.Add("Attachment.Count", 0);

    //using ServiceBusMessageBatch messageBatch = await sender.CreateMessageBatchAsync();
    await sender.SendMessageAsync(msg);
}
```

And I am getting this exception message:

> DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included
> credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information.
> https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot
>
> EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment
> variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for
> more information.
> https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
>
> ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple
> attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity
> endpoint.\r\n- Visual Studio Token provider can't be accessed at
> D:\DWASFiles\Sites\MyService-ASE\LocalAppData\.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json\r\n-
> Azure CLI not installed\r\n- Az.Account module >= 2.2.0 is not
> installed.

I'm guessing that I am either not passing credentials properly or I'm not setting up he app service principal or something to that affect.  Basically I'm trying to grant the **service** the ability to send a message to the queue, and I obviously don't know what I'm doing...

**Edit 1**
I have now tried enabling a system assigned managed identity for my app service, then I add a role assignment to my queue and choose a managed identity member, and now I can pick the managed identity of my service.  I then change my code to use `ManagedIdentityCredential` instead of `DefaultAzureCredential`, but now I get this error:

> Unauthorized access. 'Send' claim(s) are required to perform this
> operation. Resource:
> 'sb://mysericebus-sbus.servicebus.windows.net/myqueue-sbq'.
> TrackingId:82d9b43f639c4a0c990e1581de8aa5db_G21,
> SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:2023-03-15T18:57:09\r\nFor
> troubleshooting information, see
> https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/servicebus/exceptions/troubleshoot.

**Edit 2**
I was able to get it working by adding the role assignment to the service bus namespace instead of directly on the queue.  When I do that queues in the namespace inherit the roll assignment.  It works, but it seems a bit too brute force,  because now that managed identity can send to any queue in the namespace....

Comment: Are you running the code locally or in Azure?

Comment: @GauravMantri - I'm running this in Azure

Comment: Make sure you've assigned Azure Service Bus Data Sender role to your system-assigned MI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-managed-service-identity

Are you running this locally or deployed?  I ask because i don't think that locally it will have access to the system-assigned managed identity and its assigned roles.

Comment: It works if I assign my services' managed identity to the Azure service bus Data Sender role on the servicebus namespace, instead of directly on the queue.   If I do that, it gets inherited on the queue...   But that grants me send privilege to all queues in the namesplace...